# How does one go about Simulating the sound of Vacuum Tubes for Audio Apps/Plugins?

Tags: c++, audio, simulation, juce

I've started my journey in Audio Programming using C++ and the JUCE framework and one of my peers has challenged me to develop a Vacuum Tube Simulator plugin for him to use in his Home Studio.

Any piece of clue, information, links or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start by researching what tubes do to the audio curve ... possibly nothing ... then learn pitfalls of digital audio especially limits imposed by both sample rate and bit depth w.r.t. attempting to convert a continuous curve ( normal analog audio ) into points on a plot ( digital audio ) to perform analog-to-digital ( ADC ) during recording ... the the counterpart DAC during playback

Answer (score 3):

As both a musician and programmer this project sounds fascinating!

Here are a couple resources that might be helpful:

- [Tubelab](http://tubelab.com/designs/tubelab-sse/simulations/)
- [Digital
  Techniques for Modeling
  Vacuum-Tube Guitar
  Amplifiers](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/comj.2009.33.2.85)
- [Digital Implementation of Musical Distortion Circuits](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dtyeh/papers/DavidYehThesissinglesided.pdf)

Although these are not specific to C++ or the JUICE framework, they provide some higher-level theories and concepts that I hope are a helpful starting point.